# Projection operator and convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I was wondering if the projection operator onto a convex set was differentiable? [ An explanation would be helpful ] .

Comment: Take the convex set to be $\mathbb R_{\ge0}\times\{0\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Consider the behaviour of the projection near the point $(0,1)$.

Comment: Could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 4):

The projection operator is not differentiable at the boundary of a set. For example, the projection onto $\mathbb{R}^+$ is $P(x)=\begin{cases}x & \text{if } x>0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x\le 0\end{cases}$, which is not differentiable at $x=0$.